# Python magic method for missing class method?

Tags: python-3.x

I need for an abstract class to be able to handle missing **class** method. I find out how to do this for instance method with `__getattr__` but it's not working with **class method**. Is it even possible ?

I've got something like this :

```
class Container:
    _definitions = {'class_a': 'example.class_a.ClassA', 
                    'class_b': 'example.class_b.ClassB'}

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, def_id):
        # import dynamicaly
        parts = cls._definitions[def_id].split(".")
        module_name = ".".join(parts[:-1])
        class_name = parts[-1]
        __import__(module_name)
        return class_name


class AbstractClass:
    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name, *args):
        def missing_method():
            result = re.search("^(?P<class_id>[a-z0-9._-]*)$", name)
            if result:
                return Container.get(result.group('class_id'))
            raise RuntimeError("class method '{}' missing from class".format(name))

        return missing_method

class ClassA(AbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        classb = cls.class_a()
        classb.method()

class ClassB(AbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        print('Hello world')
```

Each class in my Container must extend AbstractClass to be able to magically call any class in it, like I do un classA.method().

It's working if I do not use class method, but my purpose is that every class into my container can not be instantiate cause it will be useless for my needs. It's a kind of Singleton pattern.

Is it more understandable ?

Comment: Do you mean `__getattr__` ? I can't correct your question because the change is less than 6 chars.

Comment: Could you add some examples to illustrate the behavior you're looking for and demonstrate exactly how `__getattr__()` is not working?